# How can I implement maxout with caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe

I'm very new to Caffe but want to add a maxout layer in my project. There are some code about maxout in the website,such as

[implement maxout with caffe](https://github.com/BestSonny/DeepFeature/blob/master/model/deploy.prototxt) 
My code is here:

```
layers {
  name: "conv1"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  weight_decay: 1
  weight_decay: 0
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 16
    kernel_size: 9
    stride: 1
  }
}
layers {
  name: "slice1"
  type: "Slice"
  bottom: "Conv1"
  top: "slice1A"
  top: "slice1B"
  top: "slice1C"
  top: "slice1D"
  slice_param{
    axis: 1
    slice_point: 4
    slice_point: 8
    slice_point: 12
  }
}
layers {
  name: "maxout1"
  type: ELTWISE
  bottom: "slice1A"
  bottom: "slice1B"
  bottom: "slice1C"
  bottom: "slice1D"
  top: "maxout1"
  eltwise_param {
    operation:MAX
  }
}
```

Here, I use the **SLICE** layer to divide conv1 layer to four and do **ELTWISE** operation. There will be four outputs,but i don't know how the **slice1A**, **slice1B**,**slice1C** and **slice1D** to do **MAX** operation. 
                                                                                                    The following picture is my opinion.
  [ELTWISE diagram of this code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlDpJ.png)
Thank you very much!

Comment: what exactly don't you understand?

Comment: First, thank you. I am new to stackoverflow, and my english is't very good.This is my first question asked in stackoverflow. I'm very happy to see your comment. Thanks

Comment: The ELTWISE layer in caffe may help me to implement maxout(Author: Ian J. Goodfellow) layer. But I don't know how to use ELTWISE layer. As the above code shown, how to understand bottom: "conv1A" and bottom: "conv1B" to do maxout operation in maxout1 layer.    By the way, Could you have some tutorials about the ELTWISE? thank you very much!

Comment: it seems like the answer you got pretty much covers ELTWISE layer

Comment: Do you, by any chance, mean maxpool?

Comment: Hello, @Shai I have updated my problem, could you help me solve it? Thanks.

Comment: @HarshWardhan    No, There are little difference between maxpool and maxout.

Answer (score 1):

First, to put it simply, what maxout to do is taking two or more tensors as input, which have exactly the same dimension, for example, it takes 2 10-dimension vectors as input and then, on same position of the 2 vectors choosing the maximum as maxout's output vector's elements, which will finally result in a 10-dimension vector. You can see this procedure as a **fusion** process.

Then to the **ELTWISE** layer in your code, this layer is exactly going to accomplish the above procedure. Specificially, the **ELTWISE** layer will seperately take one element from each bottom **conv1A,conv1B**, then choose the maximum from the two elements as the output **maxout1**'s element and repeat this operation successively till the last position of the bottom. The maximizing operation is assigned by
 "**eltwise_param {
    operation:MAX
  }**" 
in your code.

Comment: Oh, It's very great to see your comment. I understand how to use the ELTWISE layer to do maxout operation. I will try to do this using your method. I hope you can also help me when some error happened.      At the same time, There are a some solution about it, and it  adds the SLICE layer to do others flexible operation.  [maxout and SLICE](https://github.com/BestSonny/DeepFeature/blob/master/model/deploy.prototxt)      Thank you very much.

Comment: I see your profile, i'm very glad to know you are in China. I'm a Master student in Xidian University. Recently, I'am learning some deep learning knowledge using caffe, and i am not very familiar with caffe. So if i have some questions, could i ask you using E-mail? @Dale Song   My mail address is [kzhaoxib@hotmail.com]          thank you very much.

Comment: You can read the function Forward_cpu() in eltwise_layer. cpp to learn about how to use ELTWISE layer.@J.Zhao